# PhpStorm IDE Color Issue, Differentiate Single Quoted Color from Double Quoted Color

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

I need to know how to make PhpStorm differentiate the color of single quoted strings from double quoted strings.

Like let's say I want double quote string to be in green and single quote strings to be in red like this:

```
$stringgreen = "This String is Green Color";

$stringred = 'This String is Red Color';
```

Comment: **It is not possible** (unless, maybe, you write your own plugin for that; but I still doubt that it will work just like that -- to insert your own style into existing 3rd party logic). [offtopic]BTW, I personally see no need for this.